# $p$- adic $L$- Function of a Dirichlet character at positive integers.

Tags: number-theory, p-adic-number-theory, l-functions

Let $p$ be a prime number and $d$ a natural number with $p\nmid d$. Furthermore let $\chi$ be a Dirichlet character with conductor $d$ and $G=Gal(\mathbb{Q}(\mu_{p^{\infty}})/\mathbb{Q})$.

In the modern setting a $p$-adic $L$-function is usually seen as an element in the Iwasawa algebra $\Lambda=\mathcal{O}[[G]]$ and one can usually find something like the following result.

There exists an element $\mu_{\chi}\in\Lambda$, such that

$$
\mu_{\chi}(\phi^{-1}\kappa^{n})=(1-\chi\phi(p))p^{-n})L(\chi\phi,n)
$$
for all characters $\phi:G\rightarrow\overline{\mathbb{Q}}_p$ and all integers $n\leq0$ and $\mu_{\chi}$ is uniquely determined by this formulas. Here $\kappa$ denotes the cyclotomic character.

Now the only work where I found  a formula for positive integers is 
 http://www.numdam.org/article/SB_1998-1999__41__21_0.pdf, Theorem 1.8. Colmez also states a functional equation for $p$-adic $L$-functions. Unfortunately he doesn't state where these results come from.

Therefore my question is if someone knows more about these results, like where this is proven or at least how. The only way I could think of, is using one of the conjectural formulas for the interpolation of motivic $p$-adic $L$-functions. But these are as stated only conjectural.

Comment: All I understand is that his cyclotomic character means identifying $\Gamma=Gal(\Bbb{Q}(\zeta_{p^\infty})/\Bbb{Q})$ with $\Bbb{Z}_p^\times$ and finding some distribution $\mu_\chi$ such that  $\forall k,\int_{\Bbb{Z}_p^\times} x^{-k} d\mu_\chi(x) = (1-\chi(p) p^k) L(\chi,-k)$.  The distribution exists because $L(\chi,-k)$ is $p$-adically [continuous on odd integers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kummer%27s_congruence) when $\chi(-1) = 1$.

Comment: Identifying $\int_{\Bbb{Z}_p^\times} x^{-k} d\mu_\chi(x)$ with $\int_{\Gamma} \chi_{cycl}^{-k} d\mu_\chi$ he writes $L(\chi,-k) = L_p(\chi \otimes\chi_{cycl}^{-k})$ because he will twist by other characters ($\bmod p^m$ Dirichlet characters, so characters on $\Bbb{Z}_p^\times /(1+p^m \Bbb{Z}_p)$ or characters on  $\Gamma/Gal(\Bbb{Q}(\zeta_{p^\infty})/\Bbb{Q}(\zeta_{p^m}))$): $L(\psi\chi,-k) = L_p(\chi \otimes\psi\chi_{cycl}^{-k})=\int_{\Gamma} \psi\chi_{cycl}^{-k} d\mu_\chi$